# Why do we make a Singleton Class for Retrofit Client? What happens if we don't?

Tags: java, android

I have been working on android for some time and i wondered today that :

Why do we make a `Singleton` Class for `Retrofit Client`?

What happens if we don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple,

Singleton class is used for this, so that only one object can be created at a time so this helps us in memory management.

If you don't make a class singleton then multiple instances will be created and if you don't trash those objects even by mistake then it will hold a lot of memory which is not good.

Comment: Do we need to make singleton for Database Client as well?

Comment: Yes sure, whenever same class is being used at multiple times, you can use singleton class.